# Display y value of an imageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, location

```
NSString *yValue;

yValue= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.2f", imageView.center.y];
[label setText:yValue];
```

I am trying to display the y value of an imageview as it moves on the screen. When I use this code the label simply doesn't appear. I'm not sure what im doing wrong any help is appreciated .Thanks!

Comment: test what you get with NSLog(@"yValue: %@", yValue); first and see if you see the number in console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the y value from the image's frame and then convert that to a string and then set your label's text.

Try:

```
CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;
NSString *yValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imageFrame.size.y];

[label setText: yValue];
```

** I haven't tested this code but it should be close **